Android Studio profiler and app inspection dosn't detect device
With the previous version of Android Studio everything was working fine, but now that I updated to JellyFish my app process isn't detected and no device is shown in the inspection and profiler.
I can see a device when attaching the debugger to a process and I run my project and debug it.
I have tried invalidating caches and restart, tested the cable and other devices, even installing another version of AS like Electric Eel that is working fine on my other laptop, but with no success. Also updating the SDK Components didn't help.

After much struggling , only installing new version of android studio: koala fixed problem
